# Clear or reset the wordpress posts pagination while changing filters

Tags: filter, pagination, wordpress

I think it is simple, but I don't get it. 
This is my filter:

```
<form class='post-filters'>
    <select name="filter">
        <?php
        $filter_options = array(
            'houses' => 'Houses',
            'hotels' => 'Hotels',
        );
        foreach( $filter_options as $value => $label ) {
            echo "<option ".selected( $_GET['filter'], $value )." value='$value'>$label</option>";
        }
        ?>
    </select>
    <input type='submit' value='Filter!'>
</form>
```

Related PHP to apply the filter to the wordpress query:

```
<?php 
    global $destinations;
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $destinations = new WP_Query([
        'paged' => $paged,
        'location' => $location,
        'category_name' => urldecode(get_query_var('filter')),
        'posts_per_page' => 6
    ]);
 ?>
```

If I do select my "filter" and the result has more than six entries, I use `next_posts_link()` to see the next six results. The problem is now, if I'm on page 2 or 3 and the other filter has less than e.g. 6 entries, I will see no results while changing my filter.

How do I clear the get variable (/page/2/) while changing my filter?

Example:

```
category/subcategory/subsubcategory/page/3/?filter=houses
```

Now I select "filter" hotels

```
category/subcategory/subsubcategory/page/3/?filter=hotels
```

and the "/page/3" will not be cleared. So I can not see some posts.

Comment: Set the `action` of your form to the root URL for the posts (the first page of the filtered results)

Comment: Good point, I missed it. How do I fetch the current URL with Wordpress methods? I'm currently trying ```remove_query_arg()``` and ```home_url( $wp->request )```

Comment: Can you share a full, example URL?

Comment: @rnevius, I've added an example!

Answer (score 1):

It has been anwsered here:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/264266

```
function get_nopaging_url() {
    $current_url =  $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];

    $pattern = '/page\\/[0-9]+\\//i';
    $nopaging_url = preg_replace($pattern, '', $current_url);

    return  $nopaging_url;
}
```

You could use this function to remove the pagination in your urls with filters.

See example:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_nopaging_url(); ?>?filter=houses">
```